# Polymer inline JavaScript not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, import, polymer

**Question**
Is there some official Polymer documentation that indicates inline JavaScript does not work with Polymer html imports and whatnot?  (Details below)

**Situation**
I just got a a fairly decent size component mash-up working in Chrome and went to check it in IE 11.
- All components are using inline javascript inside the *.html import files.
- All of the html imports are loading in IE (I checked the network traffic with fiddler)
- In IE 11 all I'm getting is a partial render of the top-level template title.

**Action**
My guess is that inline JavaScript is not supported in IE when using Polymer.  I took a wild guess and broke out the top-level inline javascript into a separate .js file.

**Result**
And sure enough, I'm now seeing JavaScript running in IE. Based on what I'm seeing my guess is that inline Javascript inside HTML imports is not supported in IE 11.  Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

In general, inline JavaScript works for HTMLImports on all supported platforms.

There must be some other root cause for your symptoms.

Comment: I popped out all of the js into *.js files and all of scripts started running in Firefox and IE.  I could set  break points, see things happening, etc.  I'm nesting components, so potentially there's something going on there.

Comment: Anyway it's working, but now I have a major issue with core-signals and component nesting.  Requires components in main HTML page IE/FF and only works if components are nested in Chrome.  I'll spin up another question on this item though.